# Improving RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Is there any easy and reliable way to improve RegionPlot3D other than using the slow and sometimes useless option PlotPoints?

I did find many alternatives but none are easy and many are not reliable (that only works for some cases).

Some plots made using RegionPlot3D are so bad that results are misleading, for example when plotting a convex hull or linear domains.

Example:

```
v1 = {3, 0.5, 0.5}; v2 = {0.5, 3, 0.5}; v3 = {0.5, 0.5,3};
A = Transpose[{v1, v2, v3}];

reg=Thread[0 <= LinearSolve[A, {x, y, z}]];
IR = ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y, z}];
r=RegionPlot3D[IR,PlotRange ->{ { 0,  5}, { 0,  5}, { 0,  5}}];
Show[r, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

The result is totally unacceptable, even when you use 100 points, which is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is `DiscretizeRegion` before use `RegionIntersection`

```
v1 = {3, 0.5, 0.5}; v2 = {0.5, 3, 0.5}; v3 = {0.5, 0.5, 3};
A = Transpose[{v1, v2, v3}];
reg = Thread[0 <= LinearSolve[A, {x, y, z}]];
IR = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ reg;
RegionPlot3D[
 RegionIntersection[
  DiscretizeRegion[#, {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}] & /@ IR], 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: The intersection command seems to assume the variables x, y and z are finite. That is, the intersection only plots part of the volume. If you add  Axes -> True, and compare both results you will see they are different. Thanks.

Comment: @root Do you mean your other post ?  `v1 = {1, 0.2, 0.2}; v2 = {0.2, 2, 0.2}; v3 = {0.2, 0.2, 3};
V = Transpose[{v1, v2, v3}];
S1 = ParametricRegion[{V . {x, y, z}, x >= 0}, {x, y, z}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
S2 = ParametricRegion[{V . {x, y, z}, y >= 0}, {x, y, z}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
S3 = ParametricRegion[{V . {x, y, z}, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
Region[RegionIntersection[S1, S2, S3], BaseStyle -> Cyan]`

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted some comments since I've resolved them. If you compare the original plot in this question with the plot generated by your answer, you will see they are different. You need to add Axes -> True to see this.

Comment: @root You can add the rangement  `{{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}` in `ImplicitRegion` or `DiscretizeRegion` See the updated.