# How to increase the resolution of a RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

How can one increase the quality of the following plot

```
 RegionPlot3D[{2z>= x+y&&x-y==0},{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1},Mesh->None,MaxRecursion->6]
```

[image]

Comment: Add the option: `PlotPoints -> 40` ?

Comment: @Syed, it produces more number of vertical lines which are still distorted and blurred.

Comment: How about: `{2 z >= x + y && Abs[x - y] <= 0.02}` ?

Answer (score 3):

Some clues [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261716/improving-regionplot3d).

```
RegionPlot3D[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[{2 z >= x + y && x - y == 0}, {x, y, z}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or using `ContourPlot3D`.

```
ContourPlot3D[x - y == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 z >= x + y], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x - y == 0, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[2 z >= x + y, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]